# PHP Oracle Multi table insert as one block

Tags: php, oracle

On Linux, PHP 4.3 and Oracle 10g, I am allowing candidates to apply online for jobs. At apply button I have write insert queries like this

```
$sql1 = insert into job_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 20 values
$stmt1=OCIParse($conn,$sql1);
OCIExecute($stmt1);

$sql2 = insert into personal_info_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 50 values
$stmt2=OCIParse($conn,$sql2);
OCIExecute($stmt2);

$sql3 = insert into qualification_info_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 20 values
$stmt3=OCIParse($conn,$sql3);
OCIExecute($stmt3);
```

Problem is that due to unknown reasons, sometimes all insert queries does not run thus I cannot able to track particular information in all tables.
Is there any way that ensures all insert commands MUST runs? Or rollback the entire transaction if any insert statement does not run?
Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should not use autocommit and commit at the end of procedure if you had no errors.

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-transactions-097472.html)

```
$sql1 = insert into job_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 20 values

$sql2 = insert into personal_info_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 50 values

$sql3 = insert into qualification_info_table (…) values (…);  //inserting over 20 values

$success = true;

$sqls = Array($sql1, $sql2, $sql3);

foreach ($sqls as $sql) {
    $stmt1=OCIParse($conn,$sql);
    if ( !oci_execute($stmt1,OCI_DEFAULT) ) {    
        // If we have a problem
        oci_rollback($conn);
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
}

if($success) {
    oci_commit($conn);
}
```